# array_unique/super_unique problem

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I am trying to remove duplicates based on 'duplicate_check' for the following array. It seems neither array_unique nor super_unique function works. I also tried to compare two identical arrays with a loop inside a loop function, but it runs out of time because there are tens of thousands lines in the array. Any help?

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => abc
        [b] => 202
        [c] => 001
        [d] => 
        [e] => Graphic Commun
        [duplicate_check] => abc202001
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => abc
        [b] => 211
        [c] => 001
        [d] => Bard
        [e] => CAD Fundamentals
        [duplicate_check] => abc211001
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [a] => abc
        [b] => 211
        [c] => 001
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [duplicate_check] => abc211001
    )
```

Comment: PHP has no function `super_unique`. Mind tell us what it is, where you have it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know about your tried approach (you should add that to your question). But it seems you should just use a loop to filter entries:

```
$found = array();
foreach ($array as $i=>$row) {

    $check = "$row[a],$row[b],$row[c]";
    //$check = $row["duplicate_check"];

    if (@$found[$check]++) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

A lazy solution (but probably not to your task) could also be:

```
=array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

Comment: @mario I tried the first one but no luck. I did use the second solution with super_unique function from php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php. it does remove some duplicates but not the one i indicated above.

Comment: You need to explain the structure of your source array more detailed. For example it is unclear if `"duplicate_check"` is already part of said array, or added by that super_unique (which showing would clear things up too). Show an example for which above approach failed. Else explain the filter conditions.

Comment: @mario the 'duplicate_check' is already part of said array. Then, i have $arr = super_unique($arr).  It didn't remove the duplicates I indicated above. I am not sure it's because the value is not completely identical. If you look at [2] and [3]. The value of 'duplicate_check' is the same but [2] has value in 'd' and 'e'.

Comment: @mario in the indicated case, removing either [2] or [3] is what i want.

Comment: Then your problem is that `"duplicate_check"` does not cover all fields. So the uniqueness of `a+b+c+d+e` concatenated together is what you want to filter after?

Comment: @mario  "duplicate_check" only covers [a], [b], [c] and I want to filter a+b+c concatenated.

Comment: Almost thought so. I've changed the code above to recalculate the `duplicate_check`. Maybe that's working for you. (I suspect the precalculated entries are invalid.)